# Trace.CorrelationManager vs. ActivitySource

Tags: c#, instrumentation, open-telemetry, system.diagnostics, telemetry

I have a suite of applications that currently track Correlation IDs using `Trace.CorrelationManager` and would like to migrate to using `ActivitySource` and OpenTelemetry.

What is the correspondence, if any, between `Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId` and OpenTelemetry's Trace ID and Span ID concepts? How should we go about integrating ActivitySource into the core libraries such that the ActivitySource telemetry can be associated with the `Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId` from the calling applications?